# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder generates invalid queries for attributes written in camelCase

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Postgres 9.4.1209, Spring Boot 1.4.0 and Hibernate 5.0.9 and trying to send a dynamic paginated query to a Spring Data Repository. This results in an error whenever my model class has an attribute named in camelCase.

The generated HQL in Hibernate's QueryTranslatorImpl is correct:

```
select count(payment) from it.my.company.Payment payment where payment.externalId in (?1)
```

But the generated SQL comes out with an extra underscore where I have camelCase attribute names, so **externalId** becomes **external_id**

```
select count(payment0_.id) as col_0_0_ from payment payment0_ where payment0_.external_id in (?)
```

Unsurprisingly, this query fails, because there is no **external_id** column in my database.

I've used both the Criteria API directly, the Spring Specification API, and QueryDSL Predicates, and have the same error popping out of Hibernate each time.

As a workaround, I've tried renaming all of my model class attributes to be entirely lowercase, which takes care of the error. But I don't want rename all of my attributes to a less readable style because of this bug =/

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I'm currently debugging my way through Hibernate's HqlSqlBaseWalker, but that's not the most readable piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that postgresql has its own naming conventions.

For example name identifier like column names should be in `lower_case_with_underscores`.

There are much ansers and discussions outside regarding your problem.

Not sure if there is a "real" solution but there a good best practices and how to's.

Here are some:

[PostgreSQL naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2878408/3493036)

[Underscores or camelCase in PostgreSQL identifiers, when the programming language uses camelCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11271763/3493036)

[Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/3493036)

Hope some of this answers helps. I will also look further to is issue to find the "real" solution.

Comment: Renaming my columns to fit the naming convention is at least a much cleaner fix than renaming the model attributes themselves.